# Image position and clipping

Tags: php, javascript, css, image-manipulation

Does anybody know how to place an image in the webpage, but both position and clipping (maybe also resizing) are interactively done by user? I need it for my registration page, I've done some clipping and resizing from css and javascript, and it's not really solve the problem. If it's can be done by php, it will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a brief summary:**

- Let the user browse for and upload a
  photo.
- Validate the photo is of correct type
  and dimensions using PHP's image
  functions.
- Show the user the photo in the
  browser, along with a draggable DIV
  that they can resize and move.  This
  is the cropping area.
- When they click "Next", you transmit
  the `x,y,width,height` of the DIV to
  the server either by AJAX or simply
  as hidden fields in a form.
- Again, use the PHP image functions to
  crop the image, and then resize it.
- Save it to a permanent location.

Post a comment for further specific answers.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you're going to need to use either JavaScript or Flash to maintain intractability for a clientside resize of you image.

The following tutorial shows you how to use jQuery's simplified AJAX and PHP to upload an image to a temporary location, resize it, and save the resized copy where you desire.

Hope it helps!

http://www.webmotionuk.co.uk/jquery-image-upload-and-crop-for-php/

Answer (score 0):

Try this class

http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

All images that are being uploaded by user can be edited in anyway using php